# Hibernate map a legacy class with arg constructor

Tags: hibernate

Considering Hibernate 3,

I would like to map a legacy class to a new Db table. (I have to use a legacy model .jar and have to store these objects in a new db)
But my legacy object does not declare a default no arg constructor and i am not able to change the contract because it is part of an API model. (shared by legacy apps). I neither do not want to write a new class for this and do not want to transcode from one to other.

Let's say I have a class with 3 attributes and only a default constructor(arg0,arg1,arg2), and each arg has to be mapped with a column in db (table with 3 col). I have to store and retrieve objects.

Would it be possible without having to declare a default no arg constructor ? Using an interceptor ? would it be possible to access 3 columns to call constructor with args ?

NB : sorry, i forgot to say, no setter on these 3 attributes to ensure developpers use the 3 args constructor.

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a Interceptor that calls the constructor.

See this [forum post](https://forums.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=958960&view=previous). There are probably better resources out there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. But i do not think that solution would let me map a few columns -three for me- to a three arg constructor. I do not understand how EmptyInterceptor instantiate signature will let me do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably implement a **tuplizer** to solve this. Here is the [API doc](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/tuple/Tuplizer.html). Here is also [some documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-tuplizers) about it.